# What does an asterisk in Python 3.7 responsible for doing in this particular scenario?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I completed a Kata on CodeWars and saw someone else's code using an asterisk in a way I'd never seen. I've never really learnt what an asterisk does in python and I was wondering if anyone could explain what it's doing in this particular case?

The point of the code is returning a different message depending on how many people like something:

```
def likes(names): #names is an array of names. E.g. ["Dave", "Billy", "Bob"]
    n = len(names)
    return {
        0: 'no one likes this',
        1: '{} likes this', 
        2: '{} and {} like this', 
        3: '{}, {} and {} like this', 
        4: '{}, {} and {others} others like this'
    }[min(4, n)].format(*names[:3], others=n-2)
```

The asterisk used right before names on the last line is what I am asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the unpack operator. It causes the elements in the list to be passed as separate arguments.

Comment: So in this case, is it saying get all names up to the 3rd in the list of names?